# Product image Upload (Flash) not working in Firefox

Tags: error, ssl, image-upload

Image Upload using Flash is not working in Firefox. It works in IE and Chrome on the same system.

The usual error "ssl error invalid or self-signed certificate" appears. I tried to debug it with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), but there is either no request made at all, or a HTTP CONNECT is shown but no data sent.

I tried on different sites, all Magento 1.9+ (one 1.9.2.1), with different Certificates (from StartSSL and Comodo). The problem is on all of them with Firefox 40 and 41.0b8 an OS X and Windows.
Flash Player version is "18.0.0.232" on all devices.

On all of this devices, the Upload works with Chrome and IE/Safari.

The [Qualys SSL Test](https://dev.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) gives A or A+ for all sites.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually Firefox stopped supporting Flash (http://www.computerworld.com/article/2948012/security/adobe-flash-must-die-firefox-facebook-itbwcw.html)

Tobias Renger already made a no-flash uploader you get can from Github which works well.

https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

Comment: Google chrome also stopped supporting flash. If it still works, wait for the next upgrade: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3160644/Google-Mozilla-pull-plug-Adobe-Flash-Tech-giants-disable-program-browsers-following-critical-security-flaw.html

Comment: Actually, the extension was made by Tobias Renger, not by Openstream.

Comment: Thanks. The extension seems to work fine. Still strange why flash won't even open a SSL connection in firefox but works fine in other browsers...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your web browser uses flash, the image uploader in Magento uses flash witch is no longer active in the most up-to-date web browsers.

To fix this there are two options:

Option 1:

Install a non flash upload plugin like the one below:

https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

Option 2:

Install flash on your machine, the downside to this solution is that you will need to install flash on every machine you or your clients use to upload images.

That's why option 1 probably is the better solution.