# How to update outdated adobe flash plugin in Magento 1.9.24

Tags: magento1.9.2.4

I am getting an issue in my website. It is giving adobe flash plugin is outdated error in Windows system so the website is stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

The security patch SUPEE-8788 removes flash from Magento admin - by default on 1.9.2.4 Flash is used for product uploads. This flash uploader has an exploit in, which leaves your site vulnerable in production.

Please see SUPEE-8788 for more info
https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788

Answer (score 0):

Magento need flash player for some features to work well.... you can solve the issue by downloading Latest version here :  https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: Hi, I already tried it but its showing I have to update adobe flash on the website. Can anyone suggest how to update adobe flash in Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: @PaulJames can you try in other browsers, also check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82572/product-image-upload-flash-not-working-in-firefox and make sure your browser didt blocked using flash......

Comment: Actually, it's not the browser issue. Because it's working fine in Ubuntu system but not working in in Windows.

Comment: It's giving the following message:
"Chrome has prevented an outdated plugin "Adobe Flash" from running on this site."

Comment: can you try  in firefox or opera.....

Comment: Yes, I tried in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @PaulJames please update question with information that its working in ubuntu , not in windows, so that someone may help......